# Why does Html.DropDownListFor need a viewdata item?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, html-helper

I have attempted to modify a boilerplate account register view to include a dropdown list of all the available user roles.  Currently, the list will display properly, yet when I try to register the new user the model state is invalid.

Here is the relevant part of the model:

```
public class RegisterModel
    {
        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "User name")]
        public string UserName { get; set; }


        [Display(Name = "Role")]
        public SelectListItem Role { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Roles")]
        public List<SelectListItem> Roles { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
        [Display(Name = "Email address")]
        public string Email { get; set; }
```

...

Here is the relevant part of the controller:

```
 [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult Register()
        {
            RegisterModel initmodel = new RegisterModel();

            initmodel.Roles = new List<SelectListItem>();

            foreach (string role in Roles.GetAllRoles())
            {
                SelectListItem item = new SelectListItem();

                item.Text = role;
                item.Value = role;
                initmodel.Roles.Add(item);

            }

            return View(initmodel);
        }


        // POST: /Account/Register





[Authorize(Roles = "TelesageAdmin")]
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Register(RegisterModel model)
    {
        SQWDataContext db = new SQWDataContext();



        model.Roles = new List<SelectListItem>();

        foreach (string role in Roles.GetAllRoles())
        {
            SelectListItem item = new SelectListItem();

            item.Text = role;
            item.Value = role;
            model.Roles.Add(item);

        }

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            // Attempt to register the user
            MembershipCreateStatus createStatus;
            Membership.CreateUser(model.UserName, model.Password, model.Email, "question", "answer", true, null, out createStatus);



            if (createStatus == MembershipCreateStatus.Success)
            {
                Roles.AddUserToRole(model.UserName, model.Role.Text);
                FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(model.UserName, false /* createPersistentCookie */);

                UserProfile newuser = new UserProfile();
                newuser.UserName = model.UserName;
                newuser.canEdit = true;
                newuser.Role = model.Role.Text;

                db.UserProfiles.InsertOnSubmit(newuser);

                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
            }
            else
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", ErrorCodeToString(createStatus));
            }
        }

        // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
        return View(model);
    }
```

Any help would greatly be appreciated!

Comment: What class does your View inherit from?

Comment: Can you verify that `Roles.GetAllRoles()` is not returning null or an empty list? Because if that is `null`, then the `HtmlHelper` will look to `ViewData` to populate the `DropDownList`

Comment: @JoeTuskan , it is not return null because the dropdown is populated with all of the roles.  It is only when I submit that there is an issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Role property on your model should be a string not a SelectListItem.

When you post your form it will only post the value of the selected drop down item back under the name "Role".  The model binder can't force a string into a SelectListItem so it just gives up and you end up with your error.

---

Also you'll need to rebuild the Roles object in the [HttpPost] Action

Comment: That gives the error: The ViewData item that has the key 'Role' is of type 'System.String' but must be of type 'IEnumerable<SelectListItem>'.

Comment: Hmm.  That usually works for me, let me poke around for a moment.

Comment: What line do you get that exception at?

Comment: @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Role, Model.Roles)

Comment: I updated the post controller (update is now copied above), it no longer crashes, but regardless of what is selected, the model state is invalid.

Comment: I cleared everything, then started over this time making role a string.  That seemed to get it to work.  I'm really not sure why that didn't work the first time.